# How to setup SonarQube for a large organization

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

I am in the process of setting up SQ for a large organization. I plan to have two separate systems one for update testing and rule development. The second would be the production system where real work occurs. I will be using SQL 2014 typically when I do that I use a SQL always On group to sync to a DR server in another datacenter. My question is with a SonarQube instance does it make sense to DR the application to that level. If my organization can wait for a period of time to stand up a new server in a DR event would that be possible with a proper backup of the DB? Further if there were no backups of the DB what would be lost with a fresh new SonarQube server besides setup/config time? Is there historical value of code scans that would be lost or would the next scan of the code base have us right back to where we were in terms of critical issues found etc.?
Thanks for your replies.

Comment: Planning regular backups is essential. Any SonarQube upgrade would otherwise be a great risk. SonarQube will store all analysis data in the database, so history will be built up. We execute our analysis on regular basis with a frequency of max 1 time a day, depending on the project activity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the data is stored in the database so using DR on the database is a good idea. You **should** make backup of the database and restoring the database is also a good solution (note that you should do backup of installed plugins).

If you loose the database, you will also loose all the configuration (quality profiles, credentials, etc.) and the history of the analyzed projects.

So to restore a SonarQube instance, you have to :

1. Restore the database
2. Restore SonarQube or install the same version
3. Restore the plugins (${SONAR_HOME}/extensions/plugins)

During the first start, the ES files (${SONAR_HOME}/data/es) will be regenerated and you're instance will then be up and running.

If you have commercial plugins or if you are working with large SonarQube instance you may contact the sales team to have support on this setup.

Disclaimer : I'm working at SonarSource